# The necessary and sufficient condition for the three planes intersect in a straight line.

Tags: linear-algebra

What's the necessary and sufficient condition for the three planes $a_ix+b_iy+c_iz=d_i,i=1,2,3$ intersect in a straight line.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary and sufficient that both rang of matrix and rang of augmented matrix of this system is equal 2, and that at least two of equations are different.